# Elixir / Phoenix / Ecto: How to customize SQL query log format?

Tags: logging, elixir, ecto

In my Phoenix/Ecto apps, when I set log level to `:debug`, I see helpful log entries for each SQL query issued by Ecto, like this:

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=1.9ms
SELECT u0."id", u0."full_name", u0."email", u0."uuid", u0."auth0_uid", u0."last_signed_in_at", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = $1) LIMIT 1 [1]
[debug] QUERY OK source="projects" db=11.8ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."name", p0."uuid", p0."settings", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "projects" AS p0 WHERE (p0."uuid" = $1) LIMIT 1 ["7qDjSk"]
[debug] QUERY OK source="project_admin_joins" db=1.9ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."project_id", p0."admin_id", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at", p0."project_id" FROM "project_admin_joins" AS p0 WHERE (p0."project_id" = $1) ORDER BY p0."project_id" [2]
```

But I'd love to tweak a couple things about this format:

- Each sql query produces two lines of log output. It's important to me to have all this info on a single line, because that makes it much easier to find events in log management services like [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/).
- Ideally I'd like to strip out the quotes around the field names so the query is easier to visually scan.

How can I customize the format of the Ecto sql query logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's no such thing as customizing Ecto's logging format; instead I needed to disable the built-in logging and write my own logging function. **But this works very differently in Ecto v2 versus Ecto v3.**

---

#### Ecto v2

In `config.exs`, configure MyApp.Repo to use a new custom logger function. That function can live wherever, but in my case I've put it in `MyApp.Repo.log_query/2`:

```rb
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  # ...
  loggers: [{MyApp.Repo, :log_query, []}]
```

In `lib/my_app/repo.ex`, define the `log_query` function: (note: in my case I've hard-coded the `:debug` log level.)

```
  ...
  require Logger

  # Inspired by https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.11/lib/ecto/log_entry.ex
  def log_query(entry) do
    Logger.log(:debug, fn ->
      {ok, _} = entry.result
      source = inspect(entry.source)
      time_us = System.convert_time_unit(entry.query_time, :native, :microsecond)
      time_ms = div(time_us, 100) / 10
      # Strip out unnecessary quotes from the query for readability
      query = Regex.replace(~r/(\d\.)"([^"]+)"/, entry.query, "\\1\\2")
      params = inspect(entry.params, charlists: false)

      "SQL query: #{ok} source=#{source} db=#{time_ms}ms   #{query}   params=#{params}"
    end)
  end
```

That's it! Make sure your log level is set appropriately, restart your app, and you should see all Ecto queries logged in this new format instead of the old one.

---

#### Ecto v3

Ecto v3 encourages you to use [telemetry events](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-telemetry-events) instead of that nasty old config stuff.

In `lib/my_app/application.ex` `MyApp.Application.start/2`, you need to set up the telemetry event. Add this snippet just before the `Supervisor.start_link/2` call:

```rb
    # Subscribe to Ecto queries for logging
    # See https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-telemetry-events
    # and https://github.com/beam-telemetry/telemetry
    handler = &MyApp.Telemetry.handle_event/4
    :ok = :telemetry.attach("my_app-ecto", [:my_app, :repo, :query], handler, %{})
```

Then define your Telemetry module which for now will only have this one event handler. I saved mine in `lib/my_app/telemetry.ex`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Telemetry do
  require Logger

  # Thanks to https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-telemetry-events
  def handle_event([:my_app, :repo, :query], measurements, metadata, _config) do
    Logger.log(:debug, fn ->
      {ok, _} = metadata.result
      source = inspect(metadata.source)
      time = div(measurements.query_time, 100_000) / 10
      # Strip out unnecessary quotes from the query for readability
      query = Regex.replace(~r/(\d\.)"([^"]+)"/, metadata.query, "\\1\\2")
      params = inspect(metadata.params, charlists: false)

      "SQL query: #{ok} source=#{source} db=#{time}ms   #{query}   params=#{params}"
    end)
  end
end
```

In `config/config.exs`, configure MyApp.Repo to disable the standard Ecto logging:

```rb
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  # ...
  log: false
```

That's it! Make sure your log level is set appropriately, restart your app, and you should see all Ecto queries logged in this new format instead of the old one.